# how does the break keyword actually work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, break

why does the code still disregard the rest of the number after 5?
I thought it was supposed to skip only number five then start with the rest of the number.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
if (i == 5) {
    break; 
}
document.write(i + "<br />");
}
```

Comment: `continue` skips

Comment: I know this question seems a little odd. but I am a beginner javaScript trying to understand better, what I am being taught.

Comment: Ok...so did you replace `break` with `continue`?

Comment: more than JS, this is a concept that applies generally to any programming language. So the answers here should help you with the understanding overall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`break` will quit the loop (similar to `return` for functions), but `continue` will skip the rest of the code of that iteration and go to the next iteration:

Example - log all the numbers from `1` to `6` to the console, but do not log `3`, and stop logging altogether at `5` (do not log `4` or any other numbers):

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
  if (i == 3) continue;
  else if (i == 5) break;
  else console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot a really appreciate your answer. Plus you answer more of my questions. So I can use both break and continue in a single loop.

Comment: No worries @JohnMicheal, always glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

`break` will break out of the for loop altogether, but `continue` will skip the rest of that iteration and move onto the next.

Comment: Thank a lot that was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `continue` to skip as `break` just breaks out of the loop.

Comment: Yes, I have. And I know what they are both used for now. Thank you for your contribution God bless.